# Hibernate OneToOne Lazy loading using FieldInterceptor issue

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, one-to-one

I have followed http://justonjava.blogspot.in/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html to make OneToOne relation lazy.

It is working well in most of the cases. But in very few cases (which is random) it is failing with following exception trace:

```
com.myapp.shape.ui.exception.DataIngestionException
        at com.myapp.shape.ui.data.DataIngestionJob.importMif(DataIngestionJob.java:242)
        at com.myapp.shape.ui.service.impl.DataIngestionServiceImpl$DataImportProcess.processJob(DataIngestionServiceImpl.java:488)
        at com.myapp.shape.ui.service.impl.DataIngestionServiceImpl$DataImportProcess.run(DataIngestionServiceImpl.java:462)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Exception in thread "Thread-7" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:93)
        at com.myapp.shape.ui.service.impl.DataIngestionServiceImpl.readJob(DataIngestionServiceImpl.java:539)
        at com.myapp.shape.ui.service.impl.DataIngestionServiceImpl$DataImportProcess.processJob(DataIngestionServiceImpl.java:511)
        at com.myapp.shape.ui.service.impl.DataIngestionServiceImpl$DataImportProcess.run(DataIngestionServiceImpl.java:462)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.myapp.shape.data.dao.Place.placeShape
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:81)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside getter of com.myapp.shape.data.dao.Place.placeShape
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.MultiPropertyMapper.mapToMapFromEntity(MultiPropertyMapper.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.work.CollectionChangeWorkUnit.generateData(CollectionChangeWorkUnit.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.work.AbstractAuditWorkUnit.perform(AbstractAuditWorkUnit.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.executeInSession(AuditProcess.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:543)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:571)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.beforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor285.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at **org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:172)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: entity is not associated with the session: null
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initializeLazyProperty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:806)
        at org.hibernate.intercept.AbstractFieldInterceptor.intercept(AbstractFieldInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.intercept.javassist.FieldInterceptorImpl.readObject(FieldInterceptorImpl.java:105)
        at com.myapp.shape.data.dao.Place.getPlaceShape(Place.java:153)
```

Any idea how can I fix this issue?

Comment: From the error looks like hibernate session is getting closed prematurely. One of the ways this can happen is, if, you are loading the object in one thread (using a live session) and passing it to another thread where the object is manipulated asynchronously but, the session associated with the object was closed in 1st thread.

Comment: Every thing is happening inside single transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
                                entity is not associated with the session: null
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initializeLazyProperty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:806)
```

And [`AbstractEntityPersister`'s code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/persister/entity/AbstractEntityPersister.java.html) (line 741):

```
public Object initializeLazyProperty(String fieldName, Object entity,
                          SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException {

   final Serializable id = session.getContextEntityIdentifier( entity );

   final EntityEntry entry = session.getPersistenceContext().getEntry( entity );

   if ( entry == null ) {
      throw new
          HibernateException("entity is not associated with the session: " + id);
   }
   ...
```

You are trying to fetch an entity whose **ID field** field is being fetched as `null` (probably not found).

Check your code. Are you fetching a valid object (maybe its id is `null`?) in at `Place.getPlaceShape(Place.java:153)`?

And if you don't find anything, maybe the problem is you are using `null` or invalid parameters in those `return (Person) fieldHandler.readObject(this, "owner", owner);` and `this.owner = fieldHandler.writeObject(this, "owner", this.owner, owner);` lines of the tutorial's code.

The workaround that tutorial suggests is very low level, so you really must be sure you know what you are doing there.